# Adding two data items in a list comprehension simultaneously, after a mathematical operation

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am trying to create a function that outputs the divisors/factors of a number.

```
def divisors(number):
    limit = int(math.sqrt(number) + 1)
    divisor_list = [x for x in range(1, limit + 1) if number % x == 0]
    return divisor_list
```

As you can see, the list comprehension allows me to output only one of the two divisors. x instead of x, number/x.

Is there a way by which I can simultaneously add the two values in the list **without nesting the list**?

Comment: you can do `[(x,number/x) for x in …]`

Comment: If Python 2.x, note integer division (consider `number/float(x)`)

Comment: @jonrsharpe Or `from __future__ import division`

Comment: Why do you want to use a list comprehension?  What's wrong with a straightforward `for` loop?

Comment: @MarkDickinson Nothing wrong with them. I ended up using a loop. I thought I was missing out on something.

Comment: @fredtantini Thanks! I did figure that out from the documentation. I wanted a flat list, so did not use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either make a list of lists:

```
[[x, number / x] for x in range(1, limit + 1) if number % x == 0]
```

Or if you don't want a list of lists you would have to use something like:

```
divisor_list = []
for x in range(1, limit + 1):
    if number % x == 0:
        divisor_list+=([x, number / x])
```